# Websocket help using NodeJS on Ionos VPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, plesk

Im a noob here and in the field of what I'm trying to do too. I have started to create a multiplayer game but it was using short polling and I don't think that is going to be best long term.

After completing a basic POC I started to rebuild and decided to use websockets as a solution.

I'm running a virtual private Linux server from Ionos
Plesk is installed
I have created a subdirectory called server in httpdocs which is where the app.js file is for server creation.
Port 8080 is open
Im using http/ws for now before I attempt to go near https/wss
I have enabled NodeJS on the server and set up the following as config:

Document Root:  /httpdocs/server
Application URL:   http://[my.url]
Application Root   /httpdocs/server
Application Startup File app.js

The app.js contains:

```
var Msg = '';
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
   , wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
   wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      ws.on('message', function(message) {
         console.log('Received from client: %s', message);
         ws.send('Server received from client: ' + message);
      });
   });
```

On any web page that loads on that domain I now get an error stating 'Upgrade Required' error 426
I know that means the server wants the client to upgrade to websockets but I cant understand why the client isn't asking to upgrade back.. In my ws_test.html file I access to test the connection this is the code in the HTML body:

```
<script>

let socket = new WebSocket("ws://[my.url]/server/app.js");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("[open] Connection established");
  alert("Sending to server");
  socket.send("TEST SUCCESSFUL");
};

</script>
```

I have tried so many different things and come to the end of my tether..  I have changed the connection URL many times and the ports. I suspect NGINX may have something to do with it but I tried disabling proxy and no change.

Can anyone see any glaringly obvoius mistakes!?

Thanks SO SO much for just reading this any help will be hugely appreciated.

I have tried so many different things and come to the end of my tether..  I have changed the connection URL many times and the ports. I suspect NGINX may have something to do with it but I tried disabling proxy and no change.

Can anyone see any glaringly obvoius mistakes!?

Thanks SO SO much for just reading this any help will be hugely appreciated.